# Saving user-imported shapefile to geodatabase

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there any API or service out there that can do this? We have a SQL Server managed geodatabase (ArcSDE).

It would be ideal to be able to create a web application where someone can upload a shapefile and we save it to our geodatabase (we'll do further processing on it as the person works their way through the web app form). Is that possible from any platform? Javascript API? ArcGIS Online? .NET with ArcObjects?

I cannot find any documentation at all for any platform regarding this capability which makes me think it's not possible. I've seen documentation for displaying user-imported shapefiles on a map, but not actually saving them to a geodatabase. We have no need to do any mapping with them.

Comment: Have you considered using a scheduled task that periodically checks for zipfiles a folder? For each zipfile  unzip it, load the shapefile into the geodatabase (using arcobjects or arcpy) then delete the zipfile.  There are likely many samples showing how to upload a zipfile to a server over the web via javascript - that's not a GIS specific problem.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Thanks. I considered it but just don't know how to handle all the various files that make-up a shapefile once it's unzipped. When loading the shapefile into the geodatabase, would you just reference the file with the ".shp" extension in the script? Sorry if that's a stupid question, I'm really new to this stuff.

Comment: A [shapefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) is actually a collection of files.  How you choose to get a shapefile loaded into your geodatabase depends on how you are storing it.  If you are using native SQL geometry/geography types, then you should be able to use [Shape2sql](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial-Tools) (which would not requre an Esri license).  If the shapefield in your featureclass is SDEBINARY, I think you'll need to use either arcobjects or arcpy to get it loaded.